# Eiffel: type conformance, how to give a type instead of an instance

Tags: eiffel

### General

I don't understand why there are like 2 `generating_type` kinds, the one with exclamation point, and the other not.

### My case

I have a function returning a `DB_SERVICE[G]` from a given instance from a collection of `db_services` so that from another service I can retrieve it and call it. When I pass an instance `generating_type` to that function, the `conforms_to` returns True, as when I give `({ENUMERATE}).generating_type` it doesn't.

Why is that so?

```
-- Humanly unreadable
if attached {ENUMERATE_DB_SERVICE} {SIT_ENVIRONMENT}.app_instance.db_service_from_entity_type (item_prototype.charge_unit_relationship.secondary_prototype.an_index_relationship.secondary_prototype.generating_type) as l_enum_dbs then

-- Humanly readable but not working
if attached {ENUMERATE_DB_SERVICE} {SIT_ENVIRONMENT}.app_instance.db_service_from_entity_type (({ENUMERATE}).generating_type) as l_enum_dbs then
```

My function

```
db_service_from_entity_type (an_entity_type: TYPE[detachable DB_ENTITY]): detachable like db_services.item
    do
        across
            db_services as l_dbs
        until
            Result /= Void
        loop
            if l_dbs.item.item_prototype.generating_type.conforms_to (an_entity_type) then
                Result := l_dbs.item
            end
        end
    ensure
        service_found: attached Result
    end
```

### Edit (20190405-11:26 UTC)

As the screenshot shows, giving `{ENUMERATE}` instead of `({ENUMERATE}).generating_type` doesn't work either

[image]

Comment: What is the type of `...secondary_prototype`?

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov  `{SIT_ENVIRONMENT}.app_instance.db_service_from_entity_type (item_prototype.charge_unit_relationship.secondary_prototype.an_index_relationship.secondary_prototype` is `ENUMERATE` (`an_index_relationship: IDENTIFIABLE_MANY_TO_ONE[like Current, ENUMERATE]`)

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov if you need some more Info, I can provide you debugger screenshots of both versions

Answer (score 1):

`generating_type` returns a dynamic type of an object. Therefore, `({ENUMERATE}).generating_type` produces `TYPE [!TYPE [!ENUMERATE]]`. But you need just `TYPE [ENUMERATE]`. This can be achieved by removing the call to `generating_type` and using a detachable version of the type: `{detachable ENUMERATE}`.

The corresponding object test would look like

```
if attached {ENUMERATE_DB_SERVICE} {SIT_ENVIRONMENT}.app_instance.db_service_from_entity_type
    ({detachable ENUMERATE}) as l_enum_dbs then
```

Comment: Thx but I tried and it gave me the same result... see my edit

Comment: @Pipo I've update the code to take attachment status of the type into account.

Comment: Thx, so does the `!` before a type mean detachable? that is part of the answer I'm looking for...

Comment: `!` means `attached`. It comes from the old syntax used to denote attached types.

Comment: sorry but now I'm confused, so the execution was comparing `{!ENUMERATE}` and `{ENUMERATE}` and this was not conform. When you give `{detachable ENUMERATE}` this is traduced into `{!ENUMERATE}`??? and all that because my secondary_prototype is ENUMERATE but not detachable (the reason of a prototype on my semantic)!!!

Comment: `TYPE [ENUMERATE]` stands for `detachable ENUMERATE` and `TYPE [!ENUMERATE]` stands for `attached ENUMERATE`. And the former does not conform to the latter.